# What happened to each of The Original Forty?

Tags: harry-potter

J. K. Rowling had released (*[Harry Potter and Me](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/sources/interviews/hpm/)* and then [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-original-forty)) the original draft for the names of the students in Harry's year.

Not counting the ones crossed out, these are the original forty names:

1. Abbott, Hannah
2. Bones, Susan
3. Boot, Trevor
4. Brocklehurst, Mandy
5. Brown, Lavender
6. Bulstrode, Millicent
7. Corner, Michael
8. Cornfoot, Stephen
9. Crabbe, Vincent
10. Davis, Tracey
11. Entwhistle, Kevin
12. Finch-Fletchley, Justin
13. Finnigan, Seamus
14. Goldstein, Anthony
15. Goyle, Gregory
16. Granger, Hermione
17. Greengrass, Queenie
18. Hopkins, Wayne
19. Jones, Megan
20. Li, Sue
21. Longbottom, Neville
22. MacDougal, Isobel
23. Macmillan, Ernest
24. Malfoy, Draco
25. Malone, Roger
26. Moon, Lily
27. Nott, Theodore
28. Parkinson, Pansy
29. Patel, Madhari
30. Patel, Mati
31. Perks, Sally-Anne
32. Potter, Harry
33. Rivers, Oliver
34. Roper, Sophie
35. Runcorn
36. Smith, Sally
37. Thomas, Gary
38. Turpin, Lisa
39. Weasley, Ronald
40. Zabini, Blaise

Which ones ended up becoming characters? What were their final names? Which ones have yet to be appear?

Comment: Accio @Slytherincess

Comment: I was going to try listing the names as they were written before emendation, but I came out with 41.

Comment: There actually was a surname "Moon" in the Sorting in the first book.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Everyone with no special note ended up as a book character as-is. **Bolded** names are those we don't really know anything about.

1. Abbott, Hannah
2. Bones, Susan
3. Boot, Trevor (first name changed to Terry in the books - h/tip @Au101)
4. Brocklehurst, Mandy
5. Brown, Lavender
6. Bulstrode, Millicent
7. Corner, Michael
8. **Cornfoot, Stephen** - [**Unknown** fate](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Stephen_Cornfoot)
9. Crabbe, Vincent
10. **Davis, Tracey** (updated - As per @ibid's comment, I don't actually recall her being in canon, but don't have access to my books to double check. For some reason she was an extremely popular character in fanfic scenes though).
11. **Entwhistle, Kevin** - [**Unknown** fate](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Kevin_Entwhistle). There was [Annabel Entwhistle](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Annabel_Entwhistle) in one of the video games.
12. Finch-Fletchley, Justin
13. Finnigan, Seamus
14. Goldstein, Anthony
15. Goyle, Gregory
16. Granger, Hermione
17. Greengrass, Queenie - Discussed recently on SFF. Was likely split into book character Daphne Greengrass, and eventual FBWTFT film character [Queenie Goldstein](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Queenie_Goldstein). The process of splitting surely attracted several fanfics.
18. **Hopkins, Wayne** - [Unknown fate](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wayne_Hopkins). There was a [Carl Hopkins](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Carl_Hopkins) in the video games, much younger than Harry.
19. **Jones, Megan** - Unknown. People speculate she was included in the films. Or morphed into other canon Joneses.
20. **Li, Sue** - no canon info. But given that only one major (or any) student is a Far-Eastern origin girl, she **may** have become Cho Chang.
21. Longbottom, Neville
22. MacDougal, Isobel - possibly turned into [Morag MacDougal](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Morag_MacDougal). There are also suggestions from fans that she became Isobel McGonagall, mother of Minerva McGonagall (hat/tip @thunderforge).
23. Macmillan, Ernest
24. Malfoy, Draco
25. **Malone, Roger** - **Unknown**. Possibly crossed the fourth wall and became [actor Joe Malone from FB film](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Joe_Malone) :)
26. [Moon, Lily](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Lily_Moon) - Proto-Luna-Lovegood. As per Pottermore, "[first intimation of Luna Lovegood, this name was never used, but gave me an idea for a fey, dreamy girl. She was named before I decided on Harry’s mother’s name.]". However, there was also a character with surname of "Moon" at Harry's sorting in *PS*: `There weren't many people left now. "Moon" "Nott" "Parkinson"`
27. Nott, Theodore
28. Parkinson, Pansy
29. Patel, Madhari - possibly changed to Padma or Parvati Patil?
30. Patel, Mati - possibly changed to Padma or Parvati Patil?
31. Perks, Sally-Anne (sorted in PS)
32. Potter, Harry
33. **Rivers, Oliver** - **Unknown**. Name Oliver was re-used in Oliver Woods, Gryffindor Quidditch captain
34. **Roper, Sophie** - **Unknown**
35. Runcorn - was NOT on Pottermore "40" list (39 in length so he's missing). Possibly used for a adult wizard [Albert Runcorn](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Albert_Runcorn) in *DH*.
36. **Smith, Sally** - formerly known as Georgina. Possibly melted into [Zacharias Smith](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dean_Thomas) who was also a 'Puff.
37. Thomas, Gary - Unknown but likely morphed into [Dean Thomas](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dean_Thomas)? [@ibid's excellent comment below notes that JKR scrapbooks confirmed that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112014/what-happened-to-each-of-the-original-forty/112016?noredirect=1#comment339261_112016)
38. Turpin, Lisa
39. Weasley, Ronald
40. Zabini, Blaise

Comment: Runcorn - bad wizard? Really, _bad_ wizard? Like, even though he was Umbridge's subordinate and a really intimidating guy, he couldn't do spells well?  (just kidding)

Comment: Rowling has confirmed elsewhere (scrapbook section of her own website) that Gary was the precursor of Dean: *"“This is a very old drawing from the “The Midnight Duel” chapter of “Philosopher’s Stone”. As you can see, Dean originally joined Harry, Ron, Hermione and Neville for the adventure. As you can see from the written caption, Dean was called “Gary” in those days."*

Comment: Didn't Trevor Boot become Terry Boot?

Comment: As @smit2294 [pointed out](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112014/what-happened-to-each-of-the-original-forty?noredirect=1#comment344355_112014), there was a character surnamed "moon" in the last book.

Comment: @ibid - I can. But to be honest, too lazy/burnt-out to :(   . If you want to edit, i absolutely won't object :)

Comment: I think that Isobel MacDougal became Isobel McGonagall, mother of Minerva McGonagall.

Comment: @ibid - thanks! and done :)

Comment: When did Tracey Davis appear in canon?

Comment: @ibid - [here](https://archiveofourown.org/tags/Tracey%20Davis*s*Harry%20Potter/works)  *waves around hands like a Jedi Mind Trick*