# What are the names of everyone in the four houses in Harry's year?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I'm currently making a mind map of the *Harry Potter* universe, but when I got to filling in the houses of Hogwarts, I realised that I barely know any names.

What are the names of everyone from Harry's year?

Comment: Are you looking for everyone _ever_, or just Harry's year?

Comment: List-based questions are typically considered too broad for this site. Also, kinda boring.

Comment: @Valorum yes, but restricted lists are generally okay. *Especially* when limited to just Harry's year, this list won't be very long.

Comment: @SQB - There's no indication that the OP wants to restrict it. They're simply asking for a list of every character in HP that has a known house. That runs into hundreds of characters.

Comment: That's why I asked the OP to clarify. Also, an answer to this question could be to point the OP in the right direction, as I have tried to do by directing them to Pottermore.

Comment: @sqb - Fair enough. If the OP comes back and decides they want to restrict it to a more sensible level, I'll be happy to revisit my close vote.

Answer (score 6):

If it's just Harry's year you want, JKR had a list of forty students ready when she started writing the books, called ["The Original Forty"](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-original-forty).
Also see [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112016/19561) that tells you what happened to those original forty.

*Wizarding World* also has lists of characters, organised by house. For instance, the [Ravenclaws](https://www.wizardingworld.com/collections/ravenclaw). If you set out and explore *Wizarding World*, I think most of your question will be answered there.