# Are there any other male Gryffindors named in Harry's year, beyond the main five?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Based on the comments discussion below [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/165938/64888), I'm wondering how many students there were in each year. There have been [various speculations](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/59185/64888) about how many people attended Hogwarts in total. But it would help to know whether there was only one dorm room per gender per year or whether there were multiple dorms for each year. We'd know for sure that there are multiple dorm rooms per year if there are any other Gryffindor males mentioned in Harry's year (they have to sleep somewhere...).

Obviously, there are the 'main' five boys who sleep in the allstar dormitory:

- Harry Potter
- Ron Weasley
- Dean Thomas
- Neville Longbottom
- Seamus Finnigan

Are these the only boys who were sorted into Gryffindor as first-years in the year covered by *Philosopher's Stone*? Are there any other male Gryffindors mentioned at all in that year? I'd prefer named characters if possible but unnamed ones will also do. Arguments from silence are fine if there really aren't any.

Book answers only, please (or JKR interviews), not movie answers.

**Update:** I've stumbled upon this quote, which implies that there were unknown students (presumably, both male and female) who are unnamed but present around Hogwarts.

> "It was murder," said Harry. He could feel himself shaking. He had hardly spoken to anyone about this, least of all **thirty** eagerly listening classmates.
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 12, Professor Umbridge)*.</sub>

As far as I can gather, Umbridge's first class is only for Gryffindors (no other houses are mentioned). That means that there were roughly 22 unnamed Gryffindors, some of whom have got to be boys.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Bem - Film only

Comment: That character is not mentioned in the books!

Comment: Not only has Rowling never mentioned any Gryffindors other than these 5, I don't think there has ever been mention of more than 5 named students for any year/House/gender combination. The out-of-universe reason is that Rowling came up with a list of 40 students in Harry's year, was pleased that she had a round number, and just stopped there, without realizing that she'd made Hogwarts so tiny. Still, it seems unlikely that there are exactly ten members of each House each year, based on how the Sorting Hat works; otherwise poor Zabini would've been stuck in whatever House still had room.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happened to each of The Original Forty?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112014/19561) and of [What are the names of everyone in the four houses?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/142865/19561) (although that last one is closed as too broad).

Comment: @SQB I don't think those are dupes at all. It tells us nothing about the houses they were in.

Comment: Actually, the OG40 list is annotated by JKR herself with the houses.

Comment: @SQB - The OG40 list is an early draft which doesn't fit the published canon, and can't really be used to answer this question.

Comment: @d_hippo - Hence why I posted it as a comment...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No, it doesn't seem like it.**

I've searched for all references to Gryffindor, and I was so far unable to find any other male named Gryffindors in Harry's year.

Neville, Seamus and Dean are collectively referred to as "the other second-year Gryffindor boys" when Harry is in his second year.

> “The dormitory door flew open and in came the other second-year
>   Gryffindor boys, Seamus Finnigan, Dean Thomas and Neville Longbottom.
>   ‘Unbelievable!’ beamed Seamus.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 5 (The Whomping Willow)*</sup></sub>

In addition, Harry refers to there being only five beds in the boys' dormitory of his year. This seems to be the only boys' dormitory for Harry's year, so this seems to imply that there were only five male students in his year.

> “They reached their familiar, circular dormitory with its five
>   four-poster beds and Harry, looking around, felt he was home at last.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 5 (The Dementor)*</sup></sub>

There's also a draft list written by JKR of students who she planned to have in Harry's year, and although some things have changed (like Dean's first name), even then there were never more than five male Gryffindor students planned for Harry's year.

This quote implies that there's only one dormitory for first year boys, as Percy was in charge of all the first years, and he leads the boys through a different door from the girls, which is the room with five beds.

> “Percy directed the girls through one door to their dormitory and the
>   boys through another. At the top of a spiral staircase – they were
>   obviously in one of the towers – they found their beds at last: five
>   four-posters hung with deep-red velvet curtains. Their trunks had
>   already been brought up. Too tired to talk much, they pulled on their
>   pyjamas and fell into bed.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 7 (The Sorting Hat)*</sup></sub>

[image]

There's also an [article](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-original-forty) on Pottermore about this list, and while changes in the names, like Neville's and Hermione's last names, were discussed, there was no mention of any other Gryffindor boys being intended or planned, nor is there any other on the list.

There's also this quote, where the dormitory is relabeled to say "second-years", and is again shown to only have five beds.

> “They hurried up it, right to the top, and at last reached the door of
>   their old dormitory, which now had a sign on it saying ‘second-years’.
>   They entered the familiar, circular room, with its five four-posters
>   hung with red velvet and its high, narrow windows. Their trunks had
>   been brought up for them and placed at the ends of their beds. 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 5 (The Whomping Willow)*</sup></sub>

In addition, after Harry and Seamus have a huge fight, both of them expressed a desire not to continue sharing a dormitory with each other. Despite their clear anger, neither of them actually attempts to ask a teacher for a transfer, and Seamus resigns himself angrily to his same bed instead. While not conclusive proof, this does imply that the reason behind them not asking for a transfer could be that they knew there was no other option.

> “I’ll talk to you how I want,’ said Harry, his temper rising so fast
>   he snatched his wand back from his bedside table. ‘If you’ve got a
>   problem sharing a dormitory with me, go and ask McGonagall if you can
>   be moved … stop your mummy worrying –”
>
> ...
>
> “You know what?’ said Seamus heatedly, casting Harry a venomous look.
>   ‘He’s right, I don’t want to share a dormitory with him any more, he’s
>   mad.”
>
> ...
>
> “Seamus looked for a few seconds as though detention would be a
>   reasonable price to pay to say what was going through his mind; but
>   with a noise of contempt he turned on his heel, vaulted into bed and
>   pulled the hangings shut with such violence that they were ripped from
>   the bed and fell in a dusty pile to the floor.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 11 (The Sorting Hat's New Song)*</sup></sub>

Comment: [FGIW!](http://orig13.deviantart.net/3aa6/f/2013/303/e/1/lucky_luke_by_blackstarlgart-d6seofq.jpg)

Comment: From the linked Pottermore writing: "*While I imagined that **there would be considerably more than forty students in each year at Hogwarts**, I thought that it would be useful to know **a proportion of Harry's classmates***"

Comment: Great find with the Seamus quote! It's worth bearing in mind that he was fighting with *Ron*, who (as a prefect) could probably give Seamus detention but whom I doubt really handled dormitory allocation. Basically, it may have been above his pay grade. It's still a fascinating part of the jigsaw puzzle, though - thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Thanks! :) I don't think Ron would have handled dormitory allocation, but neither Seamus or Harry went off to go find someone who should be able to transfer them if transfers were possible, like Dumbledore or McGonagall. Instead, they stayed in the same room even though they obviously weren't happy about it.

Comment: Also, they were sulky teenagers who were sulking. They may have been prone to exaggeration. *OMG, I hate you. I'm moving out* etc.

Answer (score 6):

### There are at most four (though probably less) unnamed male gryffindors according to the books, but many more according to Rowling

We know that there were exactly twenty students in Harry's year who were in either Gryffindor or Slytherin:

> The Slytherins were already there, and so were **twenty broomsticks** lying in neat lines on the ground.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* - Chapter 9</sub>
>
> Potions lessons took place in one of the large dungeons. Thursday afternoon’s lesson proceeded in the usual way. **Twenty cauldrons** stood steaming between the wooden desks, on which stood brass scales and jars of ingredients.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* - Chapter 11</sub>

Out of these twenty, we can identify eleven students who aren't male Gryffindors:

- Blaise Zabini
- Draco Malfoy
- Gregory Goyle
- Millicent Bulstrode
- Vincent Crabbe
- Daphne Greengrass
- Theodore Nott
- Pansy Parkinson
- Hermione Granger
- Lavendar Brown
- Parvati Patil

This puts the maximum number of unnamed male gryffindors in harry's year at four.

[image: 20 students - 11 non-male-gryffindors - 5-named-male-gryffindors = 4 unkown students]

Of course, some of these four unknown students are probably females and/or Slytherins. It's also possible that there were extra brooms/cauldrons.

---

According to J.K. Rowling, however, there are 1,000 students in Hogwarts, and the ones who are named in the books are just a small subset.
This would give us about 18 students per house per year per gender or about twelve unnamed Gryffindor males.

> **Question:** How many students attend Hogwarts, and how many students per year per house?
>   **J.K. Rowling responds:** There are about a thousand students at Hogwarts.
>
> <sub>["About the Books: transcript of J.K. Rowling's live interview on Scholastic.com," Scholastic.com, 16 October 2000](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-scholastic-chat.htm)</sub>
>
> While I imagined that **there would be considerably more than forty students in each year at Hogwarts**, I thought that it would be useful to know **a proportion of Harry's classmates**, and to have names at my fingertips when action was taking place around the school.
>
> <sub>[Pottermore - The Original Forty](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-original-forty)</sub>

Books are higher canon than Rowling, [especially where any type of numbers are involved](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/143313/55866), so we can probably ignore her statements.

Comment: I thought the 20 broomsticks and 20 cauldrons indicated each house had 10 students per year.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Or 11-9, 12-8, etc. While it may be most likely that they were equal, it isn't necessarily true.

Comment: @curiousdannii it simply means there were 20 students to a class. There maybe another class at another time. Mind you, that means each class can really only have one hour a week with each teacher if there are 8 classes per year group. I guess it's another case of details not making a good story - the school really needs at least three or more teachers per subject - I feel sorry for Shape having to substitute for DADA and still run his potions classes.

Comment: Minor point, but since students buy and bring their own cauldrons, I doubt there would be any extras.

Comment: It is not my opinion that “books are higher canon than Rowling.” They are, in effect, the same thing.

Comment: @Adamant - In my opinion books are usually higher because Rowling has been known to make mistakes when saying things ad-hoc during interviews. The exception would be when she specifically says she's aware that the books say otherwise. Of course if there's no contradiction than both are the same canon level.

Comment: I'm interested in how the quote in my update affects your answer.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Either Ravenclaw was very big or at least three houses were present. [This essay goes more in depth](http://members.madasafish.com/~cj_whitehound/Fanfic/numbers.htm).

Comment: Phwar! That link is *amazing*.

Answer (score 1):

**Definitely not.**

There are only five Gryffindor boys in Harry's year, and [the page about Bem on the Harry Potter wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Bem) confirms this, if you scroll down to the *Behind the Scenes* section.

> **Behind the scenes**
>
> Like the character Nigel Wolpert, Bem is not
> mentioned in the books, but is credited in the films. Played by Ekow
> Quartey, the character is listed in the credits for Prisoner of
> Azkaban as simply "Boy 1". However, on the Prisoner of Azkaban DVD,
> the closed captions identify the character as "Bem" during the
> Divination class scene.
>
> **Bem cannot be considered canon, as the books
> identify in several places that there are only five Gryffindor boys in
> Harry's year: Harry Potter, Ronald Weasley, Neville Longbottom, Seamus
> Finnigan and Dean Thomas.**

Comment: Hi, pretty good answer! :) As a newcomer to the site though, you might not know this, but many people here are reluctant to upvote primarily wiki-based answers, as the wiki isn't a very reliable source.

Comment: I see. Well, we all have to start somewhere, right?

Comment: Of course! :) That's why I told you, so you'll know what people here look for in answers. It varies from person to person, but there are general guidelines.

Comment: Definitely. I generally stay on Mathematics and Stack Overflow, but scifi and specifically Harry Potter is a passion of mine. I'll be sure to keep those guidelines in mind as a traverse this site. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Oh that's cool! As you can probably have guessed from the username, I like the Harry Potter series as well. :) No problem, happy to help!

Comment: The wiki itself isn't really considered a canon source. If you can show these "several places" where the books "identify that there are only five Gryffindor boys in Harry's year" then you'd have a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171615/how-many-students-attended-hogwarts/191269#191269) to the question of total number of students in Hogwarts, we never find Harry's year taking Defense Against the Dark Arts with another house (excepting NEWTs when there are too few students), yet in Harry's fifth year Defense Against the Dark Arts class there were 30 students. Unless over 80% of Harry's Gryffindor year was female (statistically unlikely), there would have had to be other males in Gryffindor in Harry's year. And while it is true that in that same answer I did note that the evidence from classes in previous years indicates that the number of Gryffindors in Harry's year was much smaller, which would be a problem for my point here, I did propose a(n unpopular) resolution to the contradiction in [a different answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28039/are-there-canon-examples-of-students-permanently-transferring-from-one-school-to/196518#196518) which would still support my point here.

Moreover, in another section of [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171615/how-many-students-attended-hogwarts/191269#191269) to the number of total students in Hogwarts, I showed that based on the Quidditch tryouts in *Half-Blood Prince* there would have been over 130 students in Gryffindor. Harry's year has only eight named students:

1. Harry
2. Ron
3. Neville
4. Dean
5. Seamus
6. Hermione
7. Parvati
8. Lavender

If we assume that there were no unnamed students in Harry's year we are left with the strange situation in which Harry's year would have had 8 students while the other years would be averaging around 20 students.

Additionally, there aren't many named students in other years in Gryffindor either. During *Half-Blood Prince* we only know of about 20 named Gryffindors — the eight in Harry's year plus:

9. Katie Bell
10. Cormac McLaggen
11. Ginny Weasley
12. Demelza Robins
13. Colin Creevey
14. Dennis Creevey
15. Ritchie Coot
16. Jimmy Peakes
17. Jack Sloper
18. Andrew Kirke
19. Euan Abercrombie
20. Natalie McDonald
21. Romilda Vane

So we're looking at well over 100 unnamed Gryffindor students. Why *wouldn't* some of them be in Harry's year and be male (particularly if we take the fifth year Defense Against the Dark Arts class size at face value)?

Of course, [as Bellatrix noted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/165971/100430), there are only five beds in Harry's dormitory, so we would have to then assume that there were additional unmentioned dormitories servicing the other male students in Harry's year.

Comment: [JKR MATHS!!!](https://i.imgflip.com/2p79r6.jpg)

Comment: There's at least one possible reason why Harry's year might have fewer students than usual. Perhaps, with the war going on, fewer children were born. Some people might have felt it was a bad time to bring children into the world; plus, with conditions as they were, there could have been a higher incidence of miscarriage (and the death of potential parents). If true, this would logically affect the years around Harry's (Ginny's year for certain). (Note that the Weasleys seemed to be trying to make up for the low numbers :-)

Comment: @Alex "If we assume that there were no unnamed students in Harry's year..." I think we *have* to assume that there were unnamed students. Expecting *all* the students in a year to be named is unreasonable, I feel.

Comment: @TheDarkLord That's my point. The "if we assume..." was to demonstrate that it's a *bad* assumption, because it leads to far-fetched conclusions.

Comment: @Alex Ah, I understand you.