# Who Started Hogwarts together with Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

Can someone please help me order things up? There are 4 houses, and it is said that each dorm has 5 beds, which means 10  students (5 boys and 5 girls) per house, times 4 is 40.

I realize it does not mean that there are 40 students each year no matter what, and they are all divided equally as 10 students for each house, so give or take.

Who are the students of each house who started school together with Harry? At least the ones we know about?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of students or just the exact number?

Comment: @Moogle I would like to see a list of each house and then research some more about each of them that I don't remember

Comment: [Closely related (and closed)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/142865/98028)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Harrypotter.fandom.com](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/1991) lists them pretty well:

> ## Gryffindor
>
> [Lavender Brown](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Lavender_Brown) (Ron's ex-girlfriend and part of Dumbledore's Army)
>
> [Seamus Finnigan](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Seamus_Finnigan) ( Partner of Harry Potter for Levitation Charm and also joined Dumbledore's Army)
>
> [Hermione Granger](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hermione_Granger) (Obviously, part of the main Trio)
>
> [Neville Longbottom](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Neville_Longbottom) (Propeminet part of all the films and slayer of Nagini)
>
> [Parvati Patil](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Parvati_Patil) ( Friend of Lavender Brown and also part of Dumbledore's Army)
>
> [Harry Potter](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Potter) (Title character)
>
> [Dean Thomas](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Dean_Thomas) (Dormatry partner of Seamus)
>
> [Ronald Weasley](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Ronald_Weasley) (Part of the main Trio)
>
> [Fay Dunbar](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Fay_Dunbar) ( fan of Quidditch, and liked to play as a Beater)
>
> [Fay Dunbar's Friend](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Fay_Dunbar%27s_friend) (Unnamed friend of Fay)
>
> ## Hufflepuff
>
> [Hannah Abbott](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hannah_Abbott) (Part of  Dumbledore's Army and married to  Neville Longbottom)
>
> [Susan Bones](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Susan_Bones) (Her entire family was killed by Lord Voldemort, part of Dumbledore's Army)
>
> [Justin Finch-Fletchley](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Justin_Finch-Fletchley) (One of the students who suspected Harry in the chamber of secret)
>
> [Wayne Hopkins](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Wayne_Hopkins) (Mentioned in Pottermore)
>
> [Megan Jones](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Megan_Jones) ( Can be [Unidentified Hufflepuff girl](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_Hufflepuff_girl_(I)) from films)
>
> [Ernest Macmillan](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Ernest_Macmillan) (Friedn of  Hannah Abbott and Justin Finch-Fletchley)
>
> ## Ravenclaw
>
> [Terry Boot](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Terry_Boot) (Not so prominent, played by Kevin Lee Yi  but mentioned mostly )
>
> [Mandy Brocklehurst](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Mandy_Brocklehurst) (Possibly played by Christina Petrou in the film)
>
> [Michael Corner](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Corner) ( Ginny Weasley's ex and take part in  D.A. meeting and practice disarming)
>
> [Anthony Goldstein](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Anthony_Goldstein) (Appeared in D.A. meeting in film and part of Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix (video game))
>
> [Sue Li](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Sue_Li) (Mentioned in Pottermore and in Harry Potter and Me)
>
> [Morag MacDougal](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Morag_MacDougal) (Appeared in  Philosopher's Stone film )
>
> [Padma Patil](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Padma_Patil) (Sister of Parvati Patil and also part of Dumbledore's Army)
>
> [Lisa Turpin](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Lisa_Turpin) (mentioend in books and pottermore)
>
> ## Slytherin
>
> [Millicent Bulstrode](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Millicent_Bulstrode) (Memeber of Inquisitorial Squad)
>
> [Vincent Crabbe](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Vincent_Crabbe) (He was more like an assistant of Draco Malfoy)
>
> [Tracey Davis](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Tracey_Davis) (Mentioned in pottermore)
>
> [Gregory Goyle](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Gregory_Goyle) ( along with Vincent Crabbe best friends cum assistant of Draco Malfoy)
>
> [Daphne Greengrass](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Daphne_Greengrass) (Debated to be part of films but present in books)
> [Draco Malfoy](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Draco_Malfoy) (Son of Lucius Malfoy and a minor antagonist cum bully)
>
> [Theodore Nott](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Theodore_Nott) (Appeared in books and Harry Potter and the Cursed Child)
>
> [Pansy Parkinson](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Pansy_Parkinson) (Part of Slytherin gang with Draco in films)
>
> [Blaise Zabini](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Blaise_Zabini) (Part of Draco Malfoy's gang)
>
> ## Unknown
>
> [Stephen Cornfoot](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Stephen_Cornfoot) (Hufflepuff or Ravenclaw) (Only present in  Harry Potter and Me and pottermore)
>
> [Kevin Entwhistle](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Kevin_Entwhistle) (Hufflepuff or Ravenclaw) (Same as Stephen)
>
> [Roger Malone](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Roger_Malone) (Hufflepuff or Ravenclaw) (Same as Stephen)
>
> [Lily Moon](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Lily_Moon)  (Hufflepuff or Slytherin) (Part of Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone book)
>
> [Oliver Rivers](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Oliver_Rivers) (Hufflepuff or Ravenclaw) (Same as Stephen)
>
> [Sally-Anne Perks](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Sally-Anne_Perks) (Gryffindor, Hufflepuff or Slytherin) (Part of Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone book)
>
> [Sophie Roper](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Sophie_Roper) (Gryffindor, Hufflepuff or Slytherin) (Same as Stephen)
>
> [Runcorn](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Runcorn) (Gryffindor, Hufflepuff or Slytherin) (Only appeared in Harry Potter and Me)
>
> [Sally Smith](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Sally_Smith) (Gryffindor, Hufflepuff or Slytherin) (Same as Stephen)

Comment: That source is dreadfully unreliable and frequently wrong. And this answer doesn't even say whether these are book characters, film characters, or from some other level of canon.

Comment: @Randal'Thor added more but now it's doomed :D

Comment: A lot of these students are certainly not what most would call canon.

Comment: To clarify, when you say that Stephen Cornfoot, Kevin Entwhistle, Tracey Davis, Wayne Hopkins, Sue Li, Roger Malone, Lily Moon, Oliver Rivers, Sally Smith were mentioned on Pottermore, do you mean specifically only "https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-original-forty" , which tells about J. K. Rowling's early plans? Megan Jones was also only mentioned there, right, as well as Moon's first name?

Comment: Where does Daphne Greengrass appear in the books? Also, do you happen to know a reference for Morag MacDougal's house?

Answer (score 0):

We do know the names of many students in Harry's year, but not all.  [You should be able to find a list in this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/142865/4918), but alas, there is none there.  [Another question does list all the known students who are in the same year as Harry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112016/4918), but from the perspective of how Rowling invented them out of universe.

[The answers under "Are there any other male Gryffindors named in Harry's year, beyond the main five?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/201681/4918) make it clear that we only know eight Gryffindors from Harry's year.

- Lavender Brown
- Seamus Finnigan
- Hermione Granger
- Neville Longbottom
- Parvati Patil
- Harry Potter
- Dean Thomas (not listed in *Stone* chapter 7, but we meet him later in chapter 9)
- Ron Weasley

There can be some uncertainty about the other houses, where there could be someone in Harry's year whose name we haven't heard.  *Philosopher's Stone* chapter 7 lists most of their names.  The following are likely the only ones named in the seven original books.

Hufflepuff:

- Hannah Abbott
- Susan Bones
- Justin Finch-Fletchley
- Ernie Macmillan (not listed in *Stone* chapter 7, first appears in *Chamber of Secrets*)

Ravenclaw:

- Terry Boot
- Mandy Brocklehurst
- Anthony Goldstein (not listed in *Stone* chapter 7, we first learn about him in Order of the Phoenix chapter 10, where we get the news that he's become a prefect)
- Padma Patil
- Lisa Turpin
- Michael Corner (not listed in *Stone* chapter 7, first appears in the Order of the Phoenix, we learn that he's in Harry's year when he shares a class with Harry in *Prince* chapter 9)

Slytherin:

- Millicent Bulstrode
- Vincent Crabbe
- Gregory Goyle
- Draco Malfoy
- Theodore Nott
- Pansy Parkinson
- Blaise Zabini

Unknown house:

- Morag MacDougal (listed in *Stone* chapter 7)
- Moon (listed in *Stone* chapter 7, but we don't meet them ever again in the books)
- Sally-Anne Perks (listed in *Stone* chapter 7)