# How do they keep the Hogwarts houses the same size?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, sorting-hat

How does the Sorting Hat prevent one house from being way bigger or smaller than the others?

---

Related: [How big were the houses at Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147979/33064)

Comment: I always just assumed that Hufflepuff was a little bigger than the others, but only Slytherin makes a big deal about it.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Do Hogwarts Houses have quotas?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7907/31394)

Comment: Who says they are?